# Determine when recursive function is finished

Tags: javascript, reflection, recursion, node.js

I have a function that does a breadth first search over a big graph.
Currently the App runs and is finished after some time.
I want to add a `finished` Event to the EventEmitter.

My first idea was to implement a counter for each `Recursive` process.
But this could fail if some `Recursive` process does not call the `counter--` method.

```
var App = function(start, cb) {
    var Recursive = function(a, cb) {
       // **asynchronous** and recursive breadth-first search
    }

    var eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    cb(eventEmitter);
    Recursive(start); 
};
```

How can I emit the `finished` message if all `Recursive` functions are finished.

**Edit** App is not searching something in the graph, it has to traversal the complete graph in order to finish. And it is not known how many elements are in the graph.

**Edit2** Something like computational reflection would be perfect, but it does not seem to exist in javascript.

The Graph is very unstable and I am doing a few nested asynchronous calls which all could fail.
Is there a way to know when all asynchronous recursive calls are finished without using a counter?

Comment: @Atticus: Odd, I don't read it that way.

Comment: The question is really unclear!! Why can't you emit in the last line in your function after `Recursive(start)` ?

Comment: After Recursive(start) is called, the App is technically finished. But the Recursive functions are still computing. I want to emit finished after all Recursive functions have finished

Comment: I'm probably seriously misunderstanding something but in my view firing the event on the line after `Recursive(start);` means it would only be executed once the function has returned, i.e. after all the recursion has finished. What am I missing? There's no multithreading here...

Comment: @innotune So you mean `Recursive` have some asynchronous calls in it?

Comment: If you want some help I suggest you post the `Recursive` function code either here or if its too big here: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: yes `Recursive` is asynchronous

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this :

```
var App = function(start, cb) {
  var pendingRecursive = 0;
  var eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  cb(eventEmitter);

  var Recursive = function(a) {
    // breadth-first search recursion

    // before each recursive call:
    pendingRecursive++;
    Recursive(/*whatever*/);

    // at the end of the function
    if (--pendingRecursive == 0){
      eventEmitter.emit('end');
    }
  }

  pendingRecursive = 1;
  Recursive(start); 
};
```

Basically, you just increment a counter before each recursive call, and decrement it at the end of the call, so you're effectively counting the number of unfinished calls, when it's zero, you can then emit your event.

Comment: what happens if, considering it is asynchronous, the `Recursive` function is called two times and those two calls are finished _before_ the third time is even called? I'd say it doesn't work. You assume, that the calls are firstly made all together, and I'd say it works for most cases. But in my case, for files and subdirectories in a huge directory, where the recursive call is called in each subdirectory after listing files and directories, this method, my guess, won't work, because the counter may reach `0` even before the listing is complete, since you assume it to work like a stack.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is single threaded.

So unless `Recursive(start);` has asynchronous calls in it like `setTimeout` or `ajax` it's safe to just trigger your finished event after calling the recursive function.

General asynchronous APIs pass around a `done` function.

So you would have

```
Recursive(start, function() {
    // trigger finished.
});

var Recursive = function(a, done) {
    ...
};
```

And it's upto users to call `done` when they are done.

Comment: recursive function also go to the event loop- so how you know when to call to done ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this based on Adriens answer

```
/**
 * Function to search for a file recursively from a base directory
 * returns an array of absolute paths for files that match the search
 * criteria
 */


let  recursiveFileSearch  = ( baseDir, fileId ) => {


    let pathsArray = [];
    pendingRecursive = 1;


    //recursive funcion to get all config paths
    let getFilePaths = ( baseDir ) => {

        //require inbuilt path and filesystem modules
        let path = require ( 'path' );
        let fs   = require ( 'fs' );

        //read the files in the base directory
        let files = fs.readdirSync ( baseDir );

        //fetch all config files recursively
        for ( let i = 0 ; i < files.length; i ++ ) {

            let file     = files [ i ];
            let filePath = path.resolve ( baseDir, file );

            //get file stats
            let fileStats = fs.lstatSync ( filePath );
            let isFile    = fileStats.isFile ( );
            let isDir     = fileStats.isDirectory ( );

            if  ( isFile && file === fileId ) {
                pathsArray.push ( filePath );
            }

            if  ( isDir ) {

                pendingRecursive++;
                getFilePaths( filePath );
            }

        }

        //decrement the recursive flag
        if (--pendingRecursive == 0){
            return pathsArray;
        }  



    };

    return  getFilePaths ( baseDir );

};


//Testing the recursive search
let baseDir = __dirname;
let filePaths = recursiveFileSearch  ( baseDir, "your file name" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a boolean outside of the function as a flag and change it's value upon reaching your targetted node? Perhaps your recursive cases can be within a case on the boolean, and when the node is found you can update it's value... Or are you asking what the base case is for your recursive function to complete?

Comment: it is more of a traversal of the complete graph than a searching. i'm asking how to know if all recursive calls in App are finished

Comment: right -- breadth first child -> siblings -> child -> siblings, repeat, right? So i would use a decrementing counter on the number of nodes total, decrementing each visit. Once 0, done, otherwise raise flag that node has been found.. would that work for your search?